# How can I add my own custom css and html to Prestashop?

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I was building my own website from scratch and realized that setting up the E-Commerce side of things would take an enormous amount of time so I decided to use Prestashop. I've already designed everything besides the actual store. I wanted to use the default prestashop theme and edit the HTML and css to make it look like my website. I've already written all the css and html but I am not sure how to add it to prestashop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing small adjustments to the theme you can use the [custom.css](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/themes/classic/assets/css/custom.css) file.

For heavy changes you will have to use `npm build|watch` in the [_dev](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop/themes/classic/_dev) folder and make your changes in `scss` files in [_dev/css](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/develop/themes/classic/_dev/css) folder.